# The FilamentPHP Wizard Form displays a Livewire error while validating form fields

Tags: laravel-livewire, filamentphp

The error below shows up whenever I try to click on 'Next' on the wizard form; the fields' error messages are not showing up. The form is not progressing to the next page if there are any errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeType')
    at isIf (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7559:35)
    at patchChildren (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7567:17)
    at patch (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7488:7)
    at patchChildren (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7641:9)
    at patch (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7488:7)
    at patchChildren (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7641:9)
    at patchChildren (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7594:11)
    at patch (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7488:7)
    at patchChildren (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7641:9)
    at patchChildren (livewire.js?id=578b80d0:7594:11)
```